# Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server - Connect to a SQL Server Mirroring Session

Tags: sql-server, oracle, mirroring, failover

An Oracle Database server is using [Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm) to define a Link Server to a Microsoft SQL Server. For the database on Microsoft SQL Server, Mirroring has been configured. So the SQL database has a failover partner.

1) How can I connect to the SQL Server Mirroring session?
2) Does [Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31043/conf_sql.htm) has a configuration to introduce the failover partner in a SQL Server Mirroring session?

[SQL Server documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484.aspx) shares these keywords for these providers:

- OLEDB Provider → FailoverPartner
- ODBC Provider → Failover_Partner
- ActiveX Data Objects (ADO)  → Failover Partner

For example an ODBC connection string to a SQL Server Mirroring session would be like this:

```
"Server=Partner_A; Failover_Partner=Partner_B; Database=AdventureWorks; Network=dbmssocn"
```

But it doesn't say anything about Oracle Database Gateway. I also couldn't find anything about introducing mirror server (failover partner) in oracle documentations.