# Connect to a SQL Server Mirror from Oracle Database

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server, mirroring, failover

I know we can create a database link to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server from Oracle database. But the problem which I faced with is the SQL database which I want to connect to has a mirror fail-over partner which is configured using SQL Server Mirroring.

As mentioned in [SQL Server documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484.aspx) we can use `OLEDB`, `ODBC` and `ADO` providers by some standard keywords to introduce fail-over partner.

What's the required setting/connection string for mirror server to enable the switching to mirror server automatically?

**Note:** Previously I asked specifically about: [Oracle Database Gateway for SQL Server - Connect to a SQL Server Mirroring Session](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153845/oracle-database-gateway-for-sql-server-connect-to-a-sql-server-mirroring-sessi) without any success. In this question I'm looking for other available solutions or knowing if it's possible at all in Oracle?

Comment: Just to be clear, you're using the Database Gateway for SQL Server (an extra cost product) rather than the Database Gateway for ODBC (which is included with your database license)?

Comment: @JustinCave In fact I'm using none of them. I just know we can define a linked server to SQL Server. Also previously I preferred to use Oracle Gateway for SQL Server since I thought probably it has such built-in feature. But now I'm interested to know the solution based on each of theme or even open to solutions which use any other technology to connect to a SQL Server Mirroring Session.

Comment: If you're using the Database Gateway for ODBC, the first step is to configure an ODBC DSN so you'd just go through the configuration screen / parameter file for your ODBC driver to specify whatever settings you want.  As long as you pick an ODBC driver that supports the functionality you need, that's all handled at the ODBC layer.

Comment: @JustinCave As mentioned in [SQL Server documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175484.aspx), the keyword `Failover_Partner` should be used to set fail-over partner in an ODBC connection, for example `"Server=Partner_A; Failover_Partner=Partner_B; Database=AdventureWorks; Network=dbmssocn"` is an ODBC connection string containing fail-over partner. Do you have any idea about where should I set this setting in an [Database Gateway for ODBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/gateways.111/b31042/configodbc.htm)? Or may be it's a TNS connection setting?

Comment: Does it make any difference if the Oracle is hosted on a Linux server?

Comment: You don't use a connection string when you're using the Database Gateway for ODBC.  You use an actual DSN.  Somewhere in the SQL Server Native Client ODBC Driver configuration screen (assuming that is the driver you are using) there will be an option to configure the failover.  If you are using a different driver (because you are on Linux and Microsoft might not provide that driver on Linux), you'd use that driver's configuration options.  So how you do it is entirely dependent on the ODBC driver.

Comment: @JustinCave It seems Microsoft has [Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server on Linux](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh568451(v=sql.110).aspx). Probably I should check its reliability and its features.

Comment: @JustinCave I guess using that driver would be the most probable solution. Thank you for sharing the information :)

Comment: Your term "create a linked server _to_ connect to a Microsoft SQL Server _from_ Oracle database" is confusing because it is backwards.  A linked server is a MSSQL construct to connect _to_ oracle _from_ MSSQL.  If you want to connect _to_ MSSQL _from_ oracle, you define a database link _in the oracle database_.  And it is _that_ construct that most of the replies have addressed.

Comment: @EdStevens It comes from my SQL Server background. In fact I'm not familiar with Oracle database well. But I guess readers can understand what I mean, anyway I edited the question. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei - much better!  ;-)   Now, I know your question is focused on the mirror-failover issues and I'm afraid I can't help you specifically with that, but since you're new to the Oracle side of things, I have a blog article that you might find helpful to better understand the basics of the gateway.  It's at http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-heterogeneous-communication/oracle-transparent-gateway/

Comment: @EdStevens Thanks for sharing information :)